# omnipay payment wall integration -Error

Tags: omnipay

I tried to implement paymentwall payment gateway integration with **Laravel** using omnipay library.After setting `setApiType`, `setPublicKey` and `setPrivateKey` and trying to call the **API**, its getting the response "**Public key is missed or invalid**" from payment wall gateway.
Actually this error is happened due to passing parameter public key as `public_Key` instead of `public_key` from the omnipay library.

The  following is the response

```
[request:protected] => Omnipay\PaymentWall\Message\PurchaseRequest Object
        (
            [endPoint:protected] => https://api.paymentwall.com/api
            [parameters:protected] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
                (
  [parameters:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [apiType] => 0
                            [publicKey] => hjghjghsdfsc5464564564e56456
                            [privateKey] => gfh4567686786787hfjfhgfgfgh
                            [amount] => 10.00
                            [currency] => USD
                            [accountId] => 
                            [description] => test Pay
                            [email] => test@gmail.com
                            [clientIp] => 112.133.236.158
                            [browserDomain] => test.com
                            [card] => Omnipay\Common\CreditCard Object



[response:protected] => Omnipay\PaymentWall\Message\Response Object
 *RECURSION*
            [zeroAmountAllowed:protected] => 1
            [negativeAmountAllowed:protected] => 
        )

    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [type] => Error
            [object] => Error
            [error] => Public key is missed or invalid
            [code] => 2111
            [log] => 
        )

)
```

Public key is missed or invalid

Answer (score 0):

As I commented in the issue that you raised on github:

- This is working for everyone else. Are you sure there isn't really an issue with your keys? Can you check that there are no spurious newlines, etc, in your key as provided to the library?
- The correct name for the public key parameter within Omnipay is publicKey. The correct name within the paymentwall library is public_key. A check of the code appears to indicate that the parameter naming is correct. The Omnipay publicKey parameter is correctly passed to the paymentwall library as public_key.